# Signs that this job ad is or is not a scam?

Tags: job-search

I am looking at [this job posting](https://ca.indeed.com/cmp/Audela-Technologies-Inc./jobs/Inside-Sales-Representative-3b87b5c85196a167?q=Audela). I find the salary of $100k questionable for a job in the solar industry in the region. The [company's website](https://audela.ca/) exists but isn't great.  I think it's unlikely but possible that the job posting is real. For example, they may be a start-up that received a big windfall from somewhere.  Or, more likely, it is a scam.

I know there are other questions on here about how to tell if a job offer is a scam: obviously I won't give them any money, and I'll be careful about personal information, as much as is possible and still apply for a job. That being said, I don't want to miss the opportunity if the job is real.

So, what are the signs that the above linked job posting is or is not a scam?

Comment: Do they have phone numbers?  Offices?  A real address listed on their website? (Forgive me for not following random links)

Comment: Yes, they appear to have a real address in a commercial building.  They have a phone number listed.

Comment: The numbers work out to about $200 per closed sale. To make 100k$ you need to close 2 sales per day, or 500 sales per year. With only 250,000 houses in all of Nova Scotia I'll bet the the *entire company* isn't closing 500 sales per year.

Comment: What is wrong with their web site? There's nothing there to suggest a scam. On the other hand, a good scam artist would presumably be able to set up a credible looking web site, if sufficiently motivated.

Comment: Use the search function and type "home extended". There are some "Lorem ipsum" pages there which suggest Web development sloppiness (they didn't finish customizing the theme), but not a scam. The "Request a quote" and "Find out more" buttons also do not work (sloppy). I guess they probably need sales reps because potential customers can't figure out the web site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fact that they state how many sales you are expected to close per day makes me suspect that part of the "salary" is commissions or incentive assuming you make those numbers... and they may not be close to realistic, depending on exactly what you would be selling, at what price, into what market, against what competition, and with how much of the market already saturated. If you can really sell 500 systems every year (2 per day), you might be worth $100k. Big if.

So I don't think this has to be a scam, but I don't think it has to be as good as it may sound to you either. Ask questions and do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

If it sounds to good to be true.......

But IF they are a valid company, and IF you are a sales deity...........

I am actually willing to bet that they are basing 100k on the highest earner they have had (assuming they are real)

And a big thing is if they mean gross or net earnings.